# Calcular tamanho do arquivo de uma dataURL (custo)

Tags: javascript, node.js, otimização, buffer, data-uri

Estou fazendo o upload de uma imagem em **base64** (`dataURL`) para uma aplicação que usa express. Como o usuário esta fazendo o "recorte" desta imagem no front-end não encontrei outra forma de enviar senão por `dataURL`... a aplicação tem um limite geral de 2mb por upload más, a validação do limite desta imagem seria de 250Kb.

Pesquisando encontrei inúmeras formas para fazer esta validação dentre as quais estou (por hora) aplicando a seguinte estratégia:

- aplicar um `RegExp` para verficar se a string é uma `dataURL`
- recuperar a parte da string codificada em **base64** usando `split()`
- decodificar o **base64** para extrair o comprimento dos dados brutos

---

```
// função para decodificar o base64
function atob(str) {
    return new Buffer(str, 'base64').toString('binary')
}
// a string (dataURL)
let avatar = req.body.avatar
// regex
let BASE64_REGEX = /^(data:\w+\/[a-zA-Z\+\-\.]+;base64)$/gi
// dividir
let arr = avatar.split(','),
    mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1], // obter o mime-type
    isBase64 = BASE64_REGEX.test(arr[0]) // testar
// decodificar e obter o comprimento dos dados brutos
console.log( 'size is: ' + atob(arr[1]).length )
```

Pesquisando um pouco mais para saber se poderia "fazer melhor" encontrei [este artigo](http://www.siddharthpandey.net/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-a-base64-encoded-string/) que relata que não é necessário "fazer todo este malabarismo" e estes dois tópicos no **SO** ([tópico A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation), [tópico B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546498/calculate-the-size-to-a-base-64-decoded-message)) que mostram a fórmula para chegar ao comprimento do arquivo.

Resolvi colocar esta fórmula em prática da seguinte maneira:

```
// a string (dataURL) (simplificado sem verificação)
let avatar = req.body.avatar.split(',')[1]
// armazenar como referência os dois últimos caracteres da string (para checar o padding)
let pad = avatar.slice(-2)
// definir o número de bytes para extrair (baseado no padding)
let padlen = (pad === '==') ? 2 : ((pad.slice(-1) === '=') ? 1 : null)
// calcular segundo a fórmula
console.log( 'size is: ' + ((avatar.length / 4) * 3 - padlen) )
```

Como o esperado de ambas as formas o resultado é o mesmo:

```
size is: 72055
```

Link para o teste no [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/DVEN72866)

---

> A pergunta em si: não é como calcular mas sim o **custo** deste calculo

Como este é um "modelo" que poderá ser usado em outras partes da aplicação e como não tenho experiencia em otimização usar a abordagem com `Buffer` seria ou não "mais custoso" (consumiria mais recursos) do que usar `slice()` e realizar a operação matemática?

Agradeço qualquer ajuda... e conhecendo as regras da comunidade, não estou em busca de respostas baseadas em opinião. Uma resposta qualificada com fontes ou modelo de teste (ou referência a um) seria bem vindo. Grato.

Comment: Recomendo testar ambas formas no https://jsperf.com para averiguar desempenho, o site é bem completo. Não tenho acesso a ele aqui onde estou agora, senão faria os testes.

Comment: Hum... se não me engano este site não roda NodeJs (apenas o javascript front-end) e por isso nem irá reconhecer o `Buffer` más agradeço seu comentário

Comment: Certo... porém, tendo em vista que o usuário vai manipular a imagem via front-end, este cálculo do tamanho da string base64 poderia ser feito no front-end também, o que tornaria o *custo* para o servidor igual a zero. mas aí depende um pouco também do público alvo e da segurança que você pretende com seu aplicativo. Todavia, não teria como obter um certo valor do `length` do base64 sem cálculos que ao exceder tal `length` já seria certo que o arquivo passou do limite estipulado? Isso evitaria cálculos.

Comment: Embora o servidor tenha limite de 2mb por formulário, não é fiável confiar na validação front-end. Além disso uso um serviço externo para armazenar arquivos por isso verificar o tamanho das imagens é **essencial**